# Hough Transform source code explanation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

```
hough_in = bwareaopen( bin_im(:,:,n),20);    
% Compute the Hough transform of the image using the hough function
[H,T,R] = hough(hough_in);
P  = houghpeaks(H,3,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); 
y = R(P(:,1));
lines = houghlines(hough_in,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
```

what does `x` and `y` represent here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x contains the thetas and y the rhos of the detected lines.

Please refer to:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html

and

https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghpeaks.html

Comment: why are they being indexed using P?

Comment: @anonymous because P contains the coordinates of the peaks in the Hough array. please read the documentation, it's all in there...